# $\emptyset$ \ $\emptyset = \emptyset$ solution emptyset minus the emptyset solution? Is there a solution?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$\emptyset$\ $\emptyset = \emptyset$ is the only solution I could conjure when thinking of the solution to this problem.

Comment: The equation is true, but what exactly is the question (i.e., where are the variables)?

Comment: A *solution* to what problem? Do you mean a *proof* of the statement?

Comment: BTW, $\emptyset\backslash\text{anything}=\emptyset$.

Comment: And $\rm anything \setminus anything = \emptyset$

Comment: Problematic title because of the site's rules.

Comment: It might help if youl you state more clearly *what* is the 'problem' and *what* is your 'solution' and also *what* is your question regarding the solution.

Comment: The question was, what is emptyset minus emptyset. Thanks for the answer! :)

Comment: @barakmanos There is no 'equation' in the question—the equality does not contain any variables.

Comment: @CiaPan: An equation does not necessarily consist of variables. It may also consists of constants only. For example, $1=1$ is an equation, and so is $1=2$. The former is a true equation, and the latter is a false equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The empty set contains no elements, hence what you are doing is removing no elements from some set, say $A$, which yields $A$, i.e. $A\backslash \emptyset = A$.

Now take $A$ to be the empty set.

Comment: Now how exactly did you manage to answer a question which is not even there?

Comment: @barakmanos Although poorly expressed, I figured his question was why the equality $ \emptyset \backslash \emptyset = \emptyset$ holds.

Comment: IMO, the word "only" implies that the OP is looking for other cases which yield a similar result (though the term "similar" remains rather obscure in the given context).

Comment: In fact, I would guess that OP is asking for all $x$ such that $x\backslash x=x$ (in which case, the only solution is indeed $x=\emptyset$). Alternatively, OP could be asking for all $x$ such that $x\backslash x=\emptyset$ (in which case, the equation is true for every $x$).

Comment: According to Bourbaki, $X=\emptyset$ is equivalent to $(\forall x)(x\notin X)$.

Answer (score 5):

Several ways to interpret your question (and an answer for each case):

- ${S        }\backslash{S        }={S        }\implies{S}={\emptyset}$
- ${S        }\backslash{S        }={\emptyset}\implies\text{true}    $
- ${S        }\backslash{\emptyset}={S        }\implies\text{true}    $
- ${S        }\backslash{\emptyset}={\emptyset}\implies{S}={\emptyset}$
- ${\emptyset}\backslash{S        }={S        }\implies{S}={\emptyset}$
- ${\emptyset}\backslash{S        }={\emptyset}\implies\text{true}    $
- ${\emptyset}\backslash{\emptyset}={S        }\implies{S}={\emptyset}$
- ${\emptyset}\backslash{\emptyset}={\emptyset}\implies\text{true}    $